If the electrostatic force is so much stronger than the gravitation force, then how do black holes form?
When most discuss black-holes, they refer to the 'singularity' at the centre. A point of theoretically infinite density at an infinitesimal point. However, if the electrostatic force repelling the protons from each other is so much stronger than the gravitation force, then how do these form? The strong nuclear force keeps the protons bonded together in the nucleus with neutrons (to the best of my knowledge), but only works over a very short range, and the electrostatic force repels the like charges of the protons in the nucleus. In my mind, there isn't really a 'singularity', but more so just missing physics that is yet to be discovered (which is exciting). If the electrostatic force is so much stronger than the gravitation force, would the repulsion of individual particles not outmatch the strength of the gravitation force, therefore keeping a true singularity from being possible to form?? What is occurring that allows gravity to condense this matter so close together?? (If you can't tell[I'm guessing you can due to this question], I have not yet finished my physics undergraduate yet. I was just pondering [and procrastinating actual assignment work] and thought this exchange might have some good answers for me and some further reading to look into).
Thanks in advance :)

To answer the question, please post an answer, not a comment.

Gravity is unique because:

there is only one type of gravitational charge

it is always attractive


If, for example, you tried to generate a huge electrostatic force by gathering together a huge positive charge you'd find it very difficult. The repulsion between the different parts of the huge positive charge would try to blow the charge apart, and environmental negative charges would try to neutralise it. The end result is there are no astronomically large electric charges in the universe.
But try this with gravity and it's easy. You can assemble as much mass as you want and gravity works with you not against you. Assemble enough mass in a small enough volume and gravity will get so strong it always wins. That's why black holes form.

Good answer though I'm not sure if this fully answers OPs question due to the misconceptions on the strong and weak nuclear force part of their question.

Maybe you could also mention that the strong & weak forces have very short ranges.

@PM2Ring that wouldn't be an answer, as gravity squeezes substances to a point in a black hole.
